# How to regex square brackets?

Tags: javascript, regex

The problem: I want to get all of the square brackets' content, and then delete them, but only if the brackets are at the beginnig of the string.

For example, a given string `[foo][asd][dsa] text text text` will return array with all of the three brackets' content (`["foo", "asd", "dsa"]`), and the string will become `text text text`.

But if the string looks like that: `[foo] text [asd][dsa] text text`, it'll take only the `[foo]`, and the string will become: `text [asd][dsa] text text`.

How can I do that using JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loop checks the start of the string for anything in square brackets, takes the contents of the brackets, and removes the whole lot from the start.

```
var haystack = "[foo][asd][dsa] text text text";
var needle = /^\[([^\]]+)\](.*)/;
var result = new Array();

while ( needle.test(haystack) ) {  /* while it starts with something in [] */
    result.push(needle.exec(haystack)[1]);       /* get the contents of [] */
    haystack = haystack.replace(needle, "$2"); /* remove [] from the start */
}
```

Comment: I have one more question. if I want to use another symbol, for example: `<<foo>>`, what should I change at the needle ?

Comment: For my code `var needle = /^<<([^>]+)>>(.*)/;` but for Brugnar's `var rule = /^(?:<<([^>]*)>>)/g;`

Answer (score 1):

Something like `var newstring = oldstring.replace(/\[\w{3}]/, "");`

Comment: Thanks, I need this, but I need an array with the oldstring too.
For example, the var `[foo][asd] text text text` Will return array with:
`
0 => 'foo',
1 => 'asd'
`

Answer (score 1):

You could proceed using a while, taking the first, adding it to an array, remove it and then do all again. This would give this :

```
var t1 = "[foo][asd][dsa] text text text";
var rule = /^(?:\[([^\]]*)\])/g;
var arr = new Array();

while(m = rule.exec(t1)){
    arr.push(m[1]);
    t1 = t1.replace(rule, "")
}

alert(arr); // foo,asd,dsa
alert(t1);  //  text text text
```